# Streaming api sample code

Tags: streaming-api

I want sample code for streaming api which should not used any package. the code should not have js package or any. i want to understand how streaming api is working. could anyone help on that please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Streaming API is always based on a package, because it is a complicated subject. [Bayeux Protocol, CometD, and Long Polling](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/BayeauxProtocolAndCometD.htm) and the related parts else where assume you already know [CometD](https://docs.cometd.org/), the underlying protocol mechanism. You would need to read an extensive amount of code and documentation to fully understand what's going on. However, I'm not dissuading you from doing so; I believe knowledge is useful, and you should seek it out. Just know that it's fairly impractical to know the details unless you plan on writing your own from scratch, and there's no reason to do so.

Comment: so if i want to build streaming api with new app i should use the package isn't it?

Comment: @Eswari If using Visualforce, you would use a package, Lightning has a component built-in for this: [`lightning:empApi`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:empApi/documentation) that you can leverage instead of writing code/importing third-party package.

Comment: should we use streaming api to get notification in another app. My requirement is to get notification in another application whenever the field gets change in salesforce.

Comment: @Eswari Yes, that's one practical use of the API.

Comment: this is my another question, please don't mind. I want the notifications in another platform. example: java. For connected app i have tested in postman application. For streaming API is there any application like postman is available to test.